# Matlab : undefined function 'digraph' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have the following code that create a graph from a matrix in which every column is a node and every two lines is a node and there is edges between them:

```
i=input('How many Subjects we have in the system:');
j=input('How many Objects we have in the system:');
B=randi([0 1], i*2,j); 
disp('The Matrix of the system is the following:')
display(B);                                 % Get the system matrix 
nNodeCol = size(B,2);                            % one node for each column of B
nNodeLine = size(B,1)/2;                         % one node for every two lines of B
% First the column nodes, then the line nodes:
nodeNames = [cellstr(strcat('column', num2str((1:size(B,2))'))) ; cellstr(strcat('line', num2str((1:size(B,1)/2)')))];
% Adjacency matrix adj, adj(i,j)=1 means there is an edge from node#i to node#j:
adj = zeros(nNodeCol+nNodeLine);                 % square matrix which size is the number of nodes
adj(1:nNodeCol, nNodeCol+1:end) = B(1:2:end,:)'; % edge from a column node to a line node is added for all the 1 in the first line of the node in the matrix
adj(nNodeCol+1:end, 1:nNodeCol) = B(2:2:end,:);  % edge from the line node to a column node is added for all the 1 in the second line of the node in the matrix
% Creation of the graph:
G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
plot(G);
```

When I run I get this error that I don't get it

```
Undefined function 'digraph' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in GRAPH (line 23)
G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
```

any suggestions ? thank you .

Comment: The problem is that there is an undefined function, `digraph`. It was introduced in 2015b, do you have that or a newer version?

Comment: I have a 2014a version , so you think the problem is the version ?

Comment: unless your MATLAB can time-travel, yes! You'd find some alternatives in the FileExchange if you search!

Comment: Thank's ....i got the 2017 version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ander Biguri, the problem is that [`digraph`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) was introduced in 2015b. You are probably using an older version.

You'd find some alternatives in the FileExchange if you search, as suggested by Sardar Usama.